# Are all weapon mods compatible?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Are there any weapon mods that can't be used with other ones. I know different verions of the same mod cannot be combined as they get replaced with better ones, but can all discreet mods be used together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope! No exclusivity! All mods work together. You can mix and match to your heart's content.

Though you better have a small heart; there are only 5 mods per weapon total.